# Slider from "fade" to "scroll right"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden menu on the right of the screen, it shows and hide by clicking a button.

```
function open_menu() {
document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:clo_menu()'></a>";
}

function clo_menu() {
document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:open_menu('></a>";
}
```

Right now it fades and all I want is to slide from right (out of the screen). Is it doable?

JSFIDDLE — http://jsfiddle.net/th1uj5wr/

Thanks.

Comment: you can check this JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8Wkgf/1/.

Comment: You mean you want something like a Facebook Like Box . That pops left on mouseon and slided right on mouse out. But in your case you want it as clickable. Instead of mouseon and out. See [Demo](http://24work.blogspot.com/p/demo.html?url=http://24work-new.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/24work-blogspot/facebook-pop-old/like-box-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your body style. This will allow you to move the menu out of the screen without creating a scrollbar:

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I'm using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to move the menu later on:

```
$("#clickme").toggle(function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().animate({right:'-100px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
});
```

Check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2881/) JSFiddle to view my working example.